# Minmax algorithm doesn't return direct child of root (returns illegal move)

Tags: java, recursion, minmax, game-theory

I am trying to create "AI" for Nine Men's Morris but I got hardstuck on `minMax` algorithm. Summing up, I was trying to find the issue for over 10h but  didn't manage to. (debugging this recursion is nasty or I am doing it badly or both)

Since I started doubting everything I wrote I decided to post my issue so someone can find anything wrong in my version of minMax. I realise it is really hard task without the whole application so any suggestions where I should triple check my code are also very welcome.

Here is link to the video, explaining minMax, on which I based my implementation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-hh51ncgDI (First video that pops up on yt after searching for minmax - just in case you want to watch the video and don't want to click the link)

**My minMax without alpha-beta pruning:**

```
    //turn - tells which player is going to move
//gameStage - what action can be done in this move, where possible actions are: put pawn, move pawn, take opponent's pawn
//depth - tells how far down the game tree should minMax go
//spots - game board
private int minMax(int depth, Turn turn, GameStage gameStage, Spot[] spots){
    if(depth==0){
        return evaluateBoard(spots);
    }

    //in my scenario I am playing as WHITE and "AI" is playing as BLACK
    //since heuristic (evaluateBoard) returns number equal to black pawns - white pawns
    //I have decided that in my minMax algorithm every white turn will try to minimize and black turn will try to maximize
    //I dont know if this is correct approach but It seems logical to me so let me know if this is wrong
    boolean isMaximizing = turn.equals(Turn.BLACK);

    //get all possible (legal) actions based on circumstances
    ArrayList<Action> children = gameManager.getAllPossibleActions(spots,turn,gameStage);

    //this object will hold information about game circumstances after applying child move
    //and this information will be passed in recursive call
    ActionResult result;

    //placeholder for value returned by minMax()
    int eval;

    //scenario for maximizing player
    if(isMaximizing){
        int maxEval = NEGATIVE_INF;
        for (Action child : children){
            //aplying possible action (child) and passing its result to recursive call
            result = gameManager.applyMove(child,turn,spots);

            //evaluate child move
            eval = minMax(depth-1,result.getTurn(),result.getGameStage(),result.getSpots());

            //resets board (which is array of Spots) so that board is not changed after minMax algorithm
            //because I am working on the original board to avoid time consuming copies
            gameManager.unapplyMove(child,turn,spots,result);

            if(maxEval<eval){
                maxEval = eval;

                //assign child with the biggest value to global static reference
                Instances.theBestAction = child;
            }
        }
        return maxEval;
    }
    //scenario for minimizing player - the same logic as for maximizing player but for minimizing
    else{
        int minEval = POSITIVE_INF;
        for (Action child : children){
            result = engine.getGameManager().applyMove(child,turn,spots);
            eval = minMax(depth-1,result.getTurn(),result.getGameStage(),result.getSpots());
            engine.getGameManager().unapplyMove(child,turn,spots,result);
            if(minEval>eval){
                minEval=eval;
                Instances.theBestAction = child;
            }
        }
        return minEval;
    }
}
```

**Simple heuristic for evaluation:**

```
//calculates the difference between black pawns on board
//and white pawns on board
public int evaluateBoard(Spot[] spots) {
    int value = 0;
    for (Spot spot : spots) {
        if (spot.getTurn().equals(Turn.BLACK)) {
            value++;
        }else if(spot.getTurn().equals(Turn.WHITE)){
            value--;
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

**My issue:**

```
    //the same parameters as in minMax() function
public void checkMove(GameStage gameStage, Turn turn, Spot[] spots) {

    //one of these must be returned by minMax() function
    //because these are the only legal actions that can be done in this turn
    ArrayList<Action> possibleActions = gameManager.getAllPossibleActions(spots,turn,gameStage);

    //I ignore int returned by minMax() because,
    //after execution of this function, action choosed by minMax()  is assigned
    //to global static reference
    minMax(1,turn,gameStage,spots);

    //getting action choosed by minMax() from global
    //static reference
    Action aiAction = Instances.theBestAction;

    //flag to check if aiAction is in possibleActions
    boolean wasFound = false;

    //find the same action returned by minMax() in possibleActions
    //change the flag upon finding one
    for(Action possibleAction : possibleActions){
        if(possibleAction.getStartSpotId() == aiAction.getStartSpotId() &&
                possibleAction.getEndSpotId() == aiAction.getEndSpotId() &&
                possibleAction.getActionType().equals(aiAction.getActionType())){
            wasFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    //when depth is equal to 1 it always is true
    //because there is no other choice, but
    //when depth>1 it really soon is false
    //so direct child of root is not chosen
    System.out.println("wasFound?: "+wasFound);
}
```

Is the idea behind my implementation of minMax algorithm correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error might exist in that you are updating `Instances.theBestAction` even while evaluating child moves.

For example, lets say 'Move 4' is the true best move that will eventually be returned, but while evaluating 'Move 5', `theBestAction` is set to the best child action of 'Move 5'. From this point on, you won't update the original `theBestAction` back to 'Move 4'.

Perhaps just a simple condition that only sets `theBestAction` when `depth == originalDepth`?

Rather than using a global, you could also consider returning a struct/object that contains both the best score AND the move that earned the score.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will try returning Pair of value and action and make an edit with an update whether it helped or not. But I don't know if solution with condition `depth == originalDepth` is possible, at least I can't imagine how to write if-statment checking when recursion made it back to the first call. But you are right, I shouldn't be letting child moves other than those on original depth to be set as `theBestAction`, yet I think recursion should go all the way back to the top and rewrite every `theBestAction` that was set before. Maybe this is the place where I've made a mistake.

Comment: You were right and your suggestion with returning object has solved my issue, ai is working as it should be. Thank you very much, you have saved me because I have a deadline in a few hours :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad I came through in time for ya. If you are interested in exploring this algorithm more, you should read up on NegaMax, Alpha-Beta pruning, and transposition tables. All of them are pretty awesome improvements.